# Testing Application Output from UDP with Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, udp, robotframework

I'm automating an application which can provide an output via TCP, UDP, both or neither. I have now created a test suite for the TCP side which simply connects telnet to the configured port and reads the output. The problem is that of course Telnet doesn't support UDP so I'm looking for recommendations on how to approach this. The output is expected to be an XML message and in this case that's the only thing I'm interested in getting out of the UDP port.

I'm currently using Python 3.8.7 and Robot Framework 4.0.1.

The application already configures everything so all the test script is required to do is to connect and listen - and provide the output as readable value for validation.

I checked the Rammbock library but it seems that it's not usable with Python 3.8 as pip was unable to install it.

Is there any Robot Framework or Python libraries or external tools that could be used to automate reading outputs from UDP similarly to Telnet with TCP?

Comment: What protocol is being used over this UDP connection? For example SNMP is over UDP and that has a library. You can call any Python code from Robot Framework, so you can use this example: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Thanks for the comment - Being quite unfamiliar with anything in networking I had not given any thought on the data transfer protocol. I'll need to look into that to see if this library would be what I'm looking for.